# Using multiple Tables instead of one BIG table?

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

Is there an advantage or disadvantage when I split big tables into multiple smaller tables when using InnboDB & MySQL?
I'm not talking about splitting the actual innoDB file of course, I'm just wondering what happens when I use multiple tables.

Circumstances:
I have a REAL big table with millions of rows (items), they are categorized (column "category").
Now, I'm thinking about using a separate table for each category instead.
I will not need the data across multiple tables under any circumstances guaranteed.

Comment: Think about [Partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html)

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking if your tables have no relevance to each other they should be in separate tables rather than a catch all table.

However, if they are related they should really reside in one table.  You can manage performance of large tables in a number of ways.  I suggest you have a look at [partitioning the tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html) if it grows too large that it starts to cause problems.

However millions of rows isn't a "REAL big table" as you say, we have many tables with tens of millions of rows, and even a few with hundreds of millions - and they perform just fine thanks to a mixture of cleaver indexing, partitioning and read replicas.

**Edit 1 - In response to comments:**

Creating dynamic tables on each of your keys in a key value pair is as you rightly say unusual, ugly and just very wrong – you’re defeating the relational part of a RDBMS.
It is impossible for me to be specific with the following as your schema and detailed information of what you want to achieve is still lacking from this question – however I feel I grasp enough to edit my original answer.

There is a huge different talking about partitioning a table within the same database and creating a new table in another database.  You ask about performance, generally speaking they should perform the same (that is a new table in a 1000gb database and one in a 0gb database) providing you have enough resources such as memory for indexing and IO on the underlying data storage and there is no bottleneck.

I can’t really work out why you would be wanting to create dynamic tables 
("table_{category}"), or storing the value / category in a text file.  This really sounds like you need a 1-N relationship and a JOIN.

Comment: thanks for your comment. my example doesn't reflect the real life scenario 1:1, I was rather trying to make an analogy.
In my RL scenario, creating separate tables would require DYNAMIC table creation, which seems unusal and ugly. I have a table with two columns "value" and "category".. so I'm thinking about creating a new table for each "category", but I don't know if there is any benefit when doing so (performance).. it would be by far easier and more elegant to keep it all in just one table, but since the data is not related I COULD use multiple tables without problems from a logistic pov.

Comment: @Benedik B is it a key value pair table? If you provide some more information such as schema and your objectives I might be able to expand my answer

Comment: thanks. I think you could call it a key/value table ("value" and "category"). Now, instead of the "category" column I could create a dynamic table "table_{category}" with only the "value" column.
I was even thinking about using textfiles instead of MySQL.
I will fill in rows every few days (but a lot) and I will read the table a few times per week (always the whole table, not parts of it).

Comment: By the way: Say I have a 1000GB innoDB database. would a NEW table in this 1000GB database perform slower than a new table in a fresh 0GB innoDB database?